# How to remove or hide powered by text from Google Translate

Tags: javascript, google-translate

Is it possible to hide or remove the `Powered by Google Translate` on the dropdown in Google Translate?

I have removed the logo part, but couldn't remove the `Powered by` text.

Here's the code:

```html
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Could you explain how did you remove the logo part?

Comment: just overriding that image's css  .goog-logo-link{
 display: none;
}

Comment: Style the google_translate_element so it has a fixed width, and set the overflow to hidden... You will only see the drop down

Comment: @AdrianSalazar  . its not working.. here is code i tried as you commented .google_translate_element{
 width:10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
  or .google_translate_element{
 width:50%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: @Robin DON'T DO THIS; you're violating Google's Attribution requirements: https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/attribution

Comment: @RobRaisch thats not a valid reason to flag a question. If you object to it, downvote.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, [the meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274906/should-questions-that-violate-api-terms-of-service-be-flagged) this came from if you are not aware. The close reason is my fault (I created the wording), but I have not voted to close because I'm still on the fence about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about violating the TOS of a third party site.

Comment: Wow, such negative reactions. It may not actually be violating Google's terms as (A) I think the OP is referring to [Google Website Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) ***not*** the Google Translate API; (B) one of the display settings Google themselves provide ([see example](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/google_translate_1.png)) actually contains no "Powered by" statement; and (C) When the user actually selects a language for translation, this displays an *additional* toolbar which clearly attributes the results to Google and should meet the requirements.

Comment: what if we're not using this as a free tool but with an API key instead?

Comment: The negative reactions to this question perplex me as well. I agree a warning that this may violate Google's TOS is justified, but other than that, there really isn't anything wrong with the question except that it denies a company worth billions of dollars more advertising space.

Answer (score 47):

You can add these lines of code in your CSS file:

```css
.goog-logo-link {
    display:none !important;
} 
    
.goog-te-gadget{
    color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**This CSS worked for me:**

```css
.goog-logo-link {
   display:none !important;
}

.goog-te-gadget {
   color: transparent !important;
}

.goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {
   color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although, previous answers regarding `display: none` and `color: transparent` may work. I use this solution to **completely erase text from html**, if you want lets say style the box itself.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".goog-logo-link").empty();
    $('.goog-te-gadget').html($('.goog-te-gadget').children());
})
```

I use jQuery in this example, however you can switch to JavaScript if you want.

Answer (score 2):

[Review image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtl5r.png) OR To remove powered by TEXT in Google Translate api, You can simply add this css.

```
.goog-te-gadget {
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the css to your stylesheet

```
#google_translate_element {
  color: transparent;
}
#google_translate_element a {
  display: none;
}
```

The first line will hide the text and the second line will hide the google translate logo.

Test it in all browsers to make sure you do not hide make the dropdown text transparent. If so, add this:

```
select.google_translate_element {
  color: black;
}
```

**to remove the "Powered by" text**

```
div.goog-te-gadget {
  color: transparent !important;
}
```

Note: I am not sure whether it is within the terms and conditions of use that you are allowed to hide the Google logo, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you decrease the height and hide the overflow, you will hide this area on the screen. Maybe not a very good solution, but it can be a good alternative.

```
<style> 
    #google_translate_element { height: 26px !important; overflow: hidden !important; }
</style>
```

You can try using this link. => https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate

Comment: Cihan Koc, I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how your code works and why it is supposed to help.

Comment: Yunnosch, If you try from the link below you will see it works. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate

Comment: I don't want to try from an external link. I want you to make your answer more helpful by adding an explanation of how and why, to what currently is a non-appreciated code-only answer. Adding that link to the answer itself (instead of hiding this in the comments) by [edit]ing it would be nice, but  does not replace an explanation. Explaining answers is a good way to help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service. Otherwise my respect for the good style of giving a matter-of-fact feedback for an (intentionally) provocative comment. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following to remove google poweredby link or image

```
#google_translate_element img
        {
            display: none !important;
        }
```

Try this to remove logo from language translator i am sure

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  $(".goog-logo-link").parent().remove();
  $(".goog-te-gadget").html(
    $(".goog-te-gadget").html().replace('&nbsp;&nbsp;Powered by ', '')
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.goog-te-gadget {line-height: 2px !important;color: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this..

```
.goog-logo-link {display:none !important; } 
.goog-te-gadget {font-size:0px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making some changes to the "googleTranslateElementInit" function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 
'google_translate_element');

var $googleDiv = $("#google_translate_element .skiptranslate");
var $googleDivChild = $("#google_translate_element .skiptranslate div");
$googleDivChild.next().remove();

$googleDiv.contents().filter(function(){
return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '';
}).remove();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inspect the elements on your server that you want to hide, and there you will find the classname(s) and then you can hide them using the *CSS* with the help of visibility or content-visibility property. Mine worked with this only ....

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: I am not convinced. Please describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Tried the code above and it did work to hide the "Powered by", but it did remove the not the Google Translate section.
What I did and it worked was add below code to the google-language-translators `style.css` in the css folder within the plugin.

```
.goog-logo-link, .goog-logo-link:link, .goog-logo-link:visited, .goog-logo-link:hover, .goog-logo-link:active {
    color: #444;
    **display: none;**
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[See Plugin active on http://sethucurryhouse.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1ZlD.png)